# Wordpress theme upload error: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm not a coder, just trying to update my wordpress site! I've bought a theme on Envato called "Birddi". When I try to upload my theme, I got this message :

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /websites/ik/ikateyou.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/birddi/inc/template.functions.php
>   on line 1748

This crashed my whole site and I couldn't get back into the admin area until I deleted the theme file. (My site is all messed up with a generic theme now so just ignore it)

Is there any way to fix this? I think this is the line...

```
$video_thumb = !empty(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($zkbirdi_meta_options['zkbirdi_format_video_local']['id'])) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url($zkbirdi_meta_options['zkbirdi_format_video_local']['id'],'full') : get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
```

Thankyou so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you contact the theme developer

Comment: I have, waiting for a reply but I wanted to see if anyone else knew how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that line with:

```
$video_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($zkbirdi_meta_options['zkbirdi_format_video_local']['id']);
$video_thumb = !empty( $video_thumb ) get_the_post_thumbnail_url($zkbirdi_meta_options['zkbirdi_format_video_local']['id'],'full') : get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
```

In earlier versions of PHP empty() should be applied to variables not values. Alternatively, you may upgrade your version of PHP but that may cause even more problems. Incidentally, I think your version of PHP may be very old - 5.4 or older.

Comment: Thankyou SO much for your help magenta! I went into my site and the PHP was only 5.3...I got my web hosting to upgrade it to 7.0 - should I try uploading the theme with the code as it was, or still change it to this new one you posted?

Comment: No if you are using 7.0 the code will work as is. The problem was the code was not compatible with PHP 5.3. That problem should be gone now but upgrades can also break things so you should check out your site throughly.